# Переопределение псевдоклассов в js

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Вот элемент:

```
<button class="nos" id="nos1" onClick="nos(0)"></button>
```

В css прописываем свойство при нажатии изменять задний фон:

```
#nos1:active{background-position: -118 -27;}
```

Затем в js заменяем самостоятельно задний фон:

```
documet.getElementById('nos1').style.backgroundPosition = "-59 -27"
```

Код из css перестает работать (кнопка не изменяется при нажатии). Почему происходит так? Есть ли способ задать псевдокласс не через html, а в js (то есть через js влиять на стиль при нажатии)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в CSS `!important`

```js
function nos(int) {
  document.getElementById('nos1').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```css
#nos1:active {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<button class="nos" id="nos1" onClick="nos(0)">Test</button>
```

Comment: Господи, это так элементарно. Спасибо

Answer (score 4):

js накладывает inline стили, у них большой приоритет.
лучше создайте класс в css, а в js добавляйте его и удаляйте.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e){
  $(e.target).addClass('bgc_red')
})
```

```css
.bgc_red{
  background-color: blue;
}

button:active{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Azaza</button>
```

Comment: Как именно нужно сделать?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQgNbK

Comment: @DemoGosha Вместо выкладывания кода на внешних источниках, используйте встроенные сниппеты

Answer (score 0):

Вы забыли единицы, пиксели, судя по всему.

```
documet.getElementById('nos1').style.backgroundPosition = "-59px -27px";
```

Так же и в CSS:

```
#nos1:active{
  background-position: -118px -27px;
}
```

Comment: по умолчанию единицы измерения - пиксели. Так что px можно не указывать

Comment: @Дмитрий уверены?

Comment: 1. https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/background-position
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80